# Tunneling to a Postgresql Server using identity-file

Tags: postgresql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to create a tunnel to a remote server, using this command:

```
sudo ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -g -L 5433:remote-ip:5432 user@dbserver.com -v
```

So, the goal is to set up tunnel that listens on local port 5433 and redirects the request to dbserver.com:5432

I have Teampostgresql set up on my local machine and try to connect to the remote DB, using the tunnel.

When I set up the tunnel and try to connect, I can see the following message in the terminal window:

```
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 5433 for 127.0.0.1 port 5432,
connect from 127.0.0.1 port 51893 to 127.0.0.1 port 5433, nchannels 5
```

Unfortunately, it's not working. 
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

[Edit]

Changed the localhost to remote-host IP, as recommended by the first commenter (who, interestingly, deleted the comment)...

[Edit2]

As per request, the results from `netstat -nlp | grep 5432`

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENS         15963    -                    /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENS         15961    -                    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Comment: I actually tried that before. Not working either. connection hangs in an endless loop. Terminal says:  listening port 5433 for 99.99.99.99 port 5432, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 51969 to 127.0.0.1 port 5433, nchannels 6

Comment: Can you please run `netstat -nlp | grep 5432` command on remote server and show result?

Comment: added the results of the netstat as an edit in my original question...

Comment: What you mean by *"Unfortunately, it's not working."*? What does not work and how do you verify that it does not work?

Comment: The request just times out. When I use Teampostgresql to connect to the remote database, add all the credentials, the request times out...